# Mysql error in php script

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I have a problem that I cant think of a solution to. Why do I got this error in my /var/log/apache2/error.log??

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/hemsida/1.php on line 6
```

I recently installed MySQL Cluster on my server and now I cant login to mysql in my php script.

My test script:

```
<?php
$db_host = "Myserver";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "XXX";
$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_passwd);
if (!$con)
 {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }
else
  echo 'connection successful';
  mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I first thought i got the wrong hostname but it seems to be right?

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname';

+---------------+-------------+
| Variable_name | Value       |
+---------------+-------------+
| hostname      | Myserver    |
+---------------+-------------+
```

I use PHP 5.5.9 and mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.19

I am new in this field so I hope someone can help me. =)

Comment: Read tutorials about `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: I'd recommend looking into [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) `mysql_connect()` is depreciated.

Comment: mysql libraries not activated on server via php

Comment: Probably phps mysql extension got deinstalled when you installed that mysql cluster package. Could be because of version conflicts. Happens if you do not pay attention very closely. You can check that using either your package management system or by using the php function `phpinfo()`.

Comment: the mysql_* library is depricated as of PHP 5.5.0, as stated in the official PHP docs. Use mysqli_* or better yet, PDO.

Comment: `I use PHP 5.5.9 and mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.19` - which linux distribution do you use?

Answer (score 0):

[Choose another API](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php), i.e. mysqli or PDO_mysql. The old mysql extension [is deprecated](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).

Your linux distribution probably ships the mysql api extensions/drivers as separate packages. E.g. ubuntu's php package seems to have PDO build into the php core but the mysql specific modules (including the PDO driver for mysql) have to be installed separately via

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```